# My AudioClip[] won't work in my PlayClipAtPoint function, how else could I play a random sound when this object gets hit?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to randomly play 1 of a certain # of sounds when my ball object hits the static object this script is attached to. The object gets destroyed once the ball hits it cutting off the sound and I don't know how I would use Random.Range. I also don't know how to make a [serialized field] that would house these multiple sounds.

I don't know how I would go about doing this as I'm new to this.

```
public class ObjectDestroyer : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] AudioClip[] breakColisionSounds;

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(breakColisionSounds,
        Camera.main.transform.position);
        Destroy(gameObject, .03f);
    }
}
```

I want the ball to hit this object, said object plays a random sound within its serialized field, while it's destroyed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to serialize your `AudioClip`s and the `AudioSource` in the Unity editor.

You will then pick a random clip from the array, assign it to the audio source, and play it.

I would also recommend you break your functionality into smaller components.

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    GetComponent<AudioCollection>().PlayRandom();
}

public class AudioCollection : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] AudioClip[] clips;
    [SerializeField] AudioSource source;

    void PlayRandom()
    {
        source.clip = clips[Random.Range(0, clips.Length)];
        source.Play();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer it worked perfectly after I added Destroy(gameObject) and made the audio source the camera.